# Visual Studio Code - Link Javascript file to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I'm trying to create an `alert` in JavaScript when HTML page is loaded.

I linked the JavaScript file to the HTML file, but the alert doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

The CSS file links successfully to the HTML file, and there are no errors on the developer tools on Chrome.

**Code**

```js
alert("page is loaded");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js.js" type="text/Javascript">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="firstParagraph">Hello world!</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please use <script src="your file path"></script> tags to include javascript code in your file.

Answer (score 4):

```js
alert("page is loaded");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="firstParagraph">Hello world!</p>    
    <script src='js.js'></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Note: as a friendly advice, always locate your own javascript files right **before closure tag of body**, because then they will run after all context is being **loaded**.

Answer (score 1):

Put your script inside `<script>` tag and replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js.js" type="text/Javascript">
```

with

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
```